# How to call the JavaScript Interface methods from android web browser?

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I tried to display a web page using the android WebView but the javascript animations are very slow ... I tried to open the same page from the browser and it works correctly ...
The problem is that i'm using using a JavaScript Interface to call some Java methods (With the WebView) :

```
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.spacetree);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
        mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "API");
        mWebView.loadUrl("MyURL");
```

And i don't know how to use this interface when i launch this page on a browser (so the animations can be displayed correctly) using this code :

```
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
        Uri.parse("MyUrl"));
        startActivity(i);
```

PS: The WebPage is stored locally ('file:///android_asset')

Comment: Have you tried to use phonegap? It's optimized for mobile webviews... else can you provide your js code?

Answer (score 0):

its very easy:

```
 mWebView.loadUrl("javascript: example()");
```

this can you do after a page is loaded and wont redirect you to a diffrent URL, if your JS is correct.

hope this helps

Comment: Thx, but as i said, i don't want to use a WebView because the it uses a very light WebClient and the JavaScript animations are very slow ... I want to launch the page on the browser and use My JavaScript Interface ...

Answer (score 0):

in file HTML create function

```
 function androidResponse(index) {
 AndroidFunction.sendToAndroid(index);
 }
```

in file java code

```
final IJavascriptHandler handle = new IJavascriptHandler(
            ListMapActivity.this);
    webMap.addJavascriptInterface(handle, "AndroidFunction");
```

define class IJavascriptHander

```
final class IJavascriptHandler {

    ListMapActivity ctx;

    IJavascriptHandler(ListMapActivity c) {
        ctx = c;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void sendToAndroid(String text) {
        final String msgeToast = text;
        // this is called from JS with passed value
        myHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // This gets executed on the UI thread so it can safely
                // modify Views
                shopMapPager.setCurrentItem(Integer.parseInt(msgeToast));
            }
        });
        Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, 2000);
        t.show();
    }
}
```

and callBack result with

```
webMap.loadUrl("javascript:androidResponse();void(0)");
```